# Get same result with NSLayoutConstraint as with Autosizing

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In my UI I have 5 buttons at the bottom. With autosizing applied to every button like on the picutre:

[image]

I get desired results:

[image] [image]

However, when I tried to do it with Autolayout in IB or in code like this:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_button1, _button2, _button3, _button4, _button5);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[_button1]-[_button2]-[_button3]-[_button4]-[_button5]-|"
                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                  metrics:nil
                                  views:viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

I get this:

[image]

Even when I try to set default width, I don't get behaviour I expected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `equal width` constraint to all the buttons and set the `horizontal space` constraint between each buttons through IB.

To set equal height
 *  Select all buttons
 *  Editor -> Pin -> Width equally

Hope this works well, as it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

`@"|-[_button1]-[_button2(==_button1)]-[_button3(==_button1)]-[_button4(==_button1)]-[_button5(==_button1)]-|"`

Gets you all equal width buttons, although they will stretch to fill the space in landscape...

Comment: +1 nice to know to create through code, Could you please tell how we can set `equal height`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before, but wasn't working because I didn't remove constraints from IB in right way, now it's ok. However, I still need them not to stretch.

Comment: @PrasadDevadiga for height (vertical, so add V:) : @"V:|-[_button1]-[_button2(==_button1)]-|"